# How to sum values of a column based on the increment values of another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, grouping

I have a table like below, now I want to sum up the values in column count as the values in day increases. I tried to query like below but it isn't working. As I am new to SQL just confused to create query which works for the above query.

Table:-

```
id     count  days
78112   4      2
78112   1      3
78112   2      5
8560    4      2
8560    4      4
9503    5      1
9503    3      2
9503    2      4
9503    5      6
```

Query:-

```
select id,sum(count),days from test group by id,days
```

This returns:-

```
id     count  days
78112   4      2
78112   1      3
78112   2      5
8560    4      2
8560    4      4
9503    5      1
9503    3      2
9503    2      4
9503    5      6
```

Excepted Output:-

```
id     count  days
78112   4      2
78112   5      3
78112   7      5
8560    4      2
8560    8      4
9503    5      1
9503    8      2
9503    10      4
9503    15      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a running total partitioned by id.

```
Select   id
        ,sum(count) over(partition by id order by days) as count
        ,days

From     t
order by cast(id as varchar(99)), days
```

| id | count | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78112 | 4 | 2 |
| 78112 | 5 | 3 |
| 78112 | 7 | 5 |
| 8560 | 4 | 2 |
| 8560 | 8 | 4 |
| 9503 | 5 | 1 |
| 9503 | 8 | 2 |
| 9503 | 10 | 4 |
| 9503 | 15 | 6 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a8QGgTGu)